# Action<T> Fire and forget?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, delegates, action

Can Action safely be used to essentially fire and forget a method with return type void in this way?

```
    public static void BeginAction(Foo input, Action<Foo> action)
    {
        action.BeginInvoke(input, EndAction, action); 
    }

    public static void EndAction(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        (result.AsyncState as Action).EndInvoke(result); 
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided that you ensure you call `EndInvoke()`, then yes.  If you forget to call `EndInvoke()` and the Action either has a return value or throws an exception, then it can leads to resources not being freed (.NET won't throw away the result or exception, it will hold them until an `EndInvoke()` call claims them).

Comment: Id be using it to copy records into a database asynchronously, 'Foo' would be a list of objects to copy. There would never be a return value but I'd log any exceptions. Not sure if its advised..

Comment: it's always a best-practice to structure your code to guarantee that `EndInvoke()` is called.  If the method behind the delegate threw an exception then calling `EndInvoke()` will rethrow that same exception instance.  However, if the async method has it's own exception handling and guarantees both (a) the method returns void and (b) the method will never generate an exception then you're safe

Answer (score 0):

One issue you would run into is app shutdown. When the user wants to close your application, how do you either (a) wait for all of these "fire-and-forget" actions to complete, or (b) terminate them gracefully?

If you need to worry about either of those things, then "fire-and-forget" probably won't work well.